# oracle trigger after update on specific field followed by insert

Tags: oracle, triggers

I'm creating a trigger that will insert a record into another table based on an after update and certain text being referenced in the update..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER NCATSPROD_PM.DEACTIVATE_USERS 
AFTER UPDATE OF "CHANGEBY_CHAR" ON NCATSPROD_PM.PM_USER_DATA 
REFERENCING NEW AS "BICSUPP"
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO NCATSPROD_PM.DEACTIVATED_USERS (USERNAME, EMAIL, DEACTIVATED_DATE) 
     VALUES (SELECT USER_ID, EMAIL, CHANGE_DATE FROM ncatsprod_pm.pm_user_data);
END;
```

When i try to compile this i'm getting an error

```
Error(1,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(1,90): PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression
```

A little unsure where i'm going wrong with this? Go to source on the error takes me to the AFTER UPDATE line but looking at examples i don't see what's up. I tried using SQL Developer's trigger wizard and that gave me the same result

Comment: First of all. You should use either `values()` clause or `select` statement in an `insert` statement, not both. `values(select)` is semantically incorrect. Second of all. Selecting from a table a trigger defined on inside the trigger will lead to `mutating table` error.

Comment: You have a REFERENCING clause. That is only valid for row triggers. But you are missing the FOR EACH ROW expression. There are other errors (as Nicholas has pointed out), but the "missing expression" probably refers to the missing FOR EACH ROW.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov - OK, I just tested, and you are right: REFERENCING clause without FOR EACH ROW is simply ignored. (Even if the alias IS used, the error thrown is different: the parser will complain about the alias, seeing it as an unknown identifier, because the REFERENCING clause is ignored.) Of course, the OP **does** want a row trigger, so other issues will arise because FOR EACH ROW is missing, but the error in the original post is caused by something else.

Comment: I removed VALUES and just did SELECT. That compiled fine. Done a little testing and it's not inserting the single record that has CHANGEBY_CHAR as BICSUPP, it's inserting everything from the source table. I thought using referencing new would only place the record that matched value BICSUPP, into the triggers insert?

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by `... and certain text being referenced in the update.` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REFERENCING clause is just used to change the names of the built-in OLD and NEW records. OLD contains the values of the row before it was updated, and NEW holds the values after it was updated. Here's an example of how you might use them.

```
create table PM_USER_DATA (user_id varchar2(20), email varchar2(20), change_date date, changeby_char varchar2(20));
create table DEACTIVATED_USERS (username varchar2(20), email varchar2(20), deactivated_date date);

insert into pm_user_data values ('test', 'test@test.com', sysdate, 'SOMEUSER');

create or replace trigger deactivate_users
    after update of changeby_char on pm_user_data
    referencing old as o1 new as n1
    for each row
begin
    if :n1.changeby_char = 'BICSUPP' then
        insert into deactivated_users (username, email, deactivated_date)
            values (:n1.user_id, :n1.email, :n1.change_date);
    end if;
end;
/

update pm_user_data set changeby_char = 'BICSUPP';

select * from deactivated_users;   
/* output: 
USERNAME             EMAIL                DEACTIVATED_DATE
-------------------- -------------------- ----------------
test                 test@test.com        10-OCT-17       
1 row selected.
*/
```